# Find specific value in Ruby hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm trying to get access to `"click_me_123"` in the following hash, but I cannot figure it out. I've tried using `['actions']['text']['value']` and `[:actions][:text][:value]` but I retrieve the appropriate value. Keen to understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
{ "type"=>"block_actions", 
  "user"=>{
     "id"=>"xxx", 
     "username"=>"xxx", 
     "name"=>"xxx", 
     "team_id"=>"xxx"
   }, 
   "api_app_id"=>"xxx", 
   "token"=>"tYfwns5zvg0g84d58OFVsWrM", 
   "container"=>{
     "type"=>"message", 
     "message_ts"=>"1643747737.666859", 
     "channel_id"=>"xxx", 
     "is_ephemeral"=>false, 
     "thread_ts"=>"1643747737.666859"
   },
   "trigger_id" => "3043308548484.1420295660643.1e4a0578e0824d3b69ed371a15842fac", 
   "team"=>{
     "id"=>"T01CC8PKEJX", 
     "domain"=>"xxx"
   }, 
   "enterprise"=>nil, 
   "is_enterprise_install"=>false, 
   "channel"=>{
     "id"=>"C0316CSCANP", 
     "name"=>"background-checksdaebc"
   }, 
   "message"=>{
     "bot_id"=>"B02V6G04XMH", 
     "type"=>"message", 
     "text"=>"New check has been started for asd", 
     "user"=>"U03054J13L1", 
     "ts"=>"1643747737.666859", 
     "team"=>"T01CC8PKEJX", 
     "blocks"=>[
       {
         "type"=>"section", 
         "block_id"=>"l2QDl", 
         "text"=>{
           "type"=>"mrkdwn", 
           "text"=>"New check has been started for asd", 
           "verbatim"=>false
         }
       }, 
       {
         "type"=>"section", 
         "block_id"=>"ma=", 
         "fields"=>[
           {
             "type"=>"mrkdwn", 
             "text"=>"*Name:*\nasd asda", 
             "verbatim"=>false
           }, 
           {
             "type"=>"mrkdwn", 
             "text"=>"*Email:*\n<mailto:asd@asdsd.dk|asd@asdsd.dk>", 
             "verbatim"=>false
           }, 
           {
             "type"=>"mrkdwn", 
             "text"=>"*Check started:*\n2022-02-01T20:35:37+00:00", 
             "verbatim"=>false
           }, 
           {
             "type"=>"mrkdwn", 
             "text"=>"*Started by:*\n<@U01CJ7BTT28>", 
             "verbatim"=>false
           }
         ]
       }, 
       {
         "type"=>"actions", 
         "block_id"=>"6Xy", 
         "elements"=>[
           {
             "type"=>"button", 
             "action_id"=>"mjLb", 
             "text"=>{
               "type"=>"plain_text", 
               "text"=>"Approve", 
               "emoji"=>true
             }, 
             "style"=>"primary", 
             "value"=>"click_me_123"
           }, 
           {
             "type"=>"button", 
             "action_id"=>"EaN2", 
             "text"=>{
               "type"=>"plain_text", 
               "text"=>"Deny", 
               "emoji"=>true
             }, 
             "style"=>"danger", 
             "value"=>"click_me_123"
           }
         ]
       }
     ], 
     "thread_ts"=>"1643747737.666859", 
     "reply_count"=>1, 
     "reply_users_count"=>1, 
     "latest_reply"=>"1643749497.845429", 
     "reply_users"=>["U03054J13L1"], 
     "is_locked"=>false, 
     "subscribed"=>true, 
     "last_read"=>"1643749497.845429"
   }, 
   "state"=>{"values"=>{}}, 
   "response_url"=>"https://hooks.slack.com/actions/xx/xx/xx", 
   "actions"=>[
     {
       "action_id"=>"mjLb", 
       "block_id"=>"6Xy", 
       "text"=>{
         "type"=>"plain_text", 
         "text"=>"Approve", 
         "emoji"=>true
       }, 
       "value"=>"click_me_123", 
       "style"=>"primary", 
       "type"=>"button", 
       "action_ts"=>"1643751685.126753"
     }
   ]
 }
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking because your question seems to state that you have a problem *"get[ting] access to `"click_me_123"`"* but then also states *"[you] retrieve the appropriate value"*. Can you please rephrase the question so that we understand what you intent is and the issue you are experiencing in achieving this? Also please format the Hash in a more vertical fashion as that is a lot of scrolling and makes it difficult to see the nesting.

Comment: In future please make your examples as simple as you can without compromising the question. Having 15 km. of lines serves only to confuse readers about the structure of the object and waste their time. It would have be sufficient, for example, to use [this hash](https://replit.com/@CarySwoveland/OrneryPotableVariety#main.rb). Notice that I assigned a variable to it (`hsh`). By doing so readers can use the variable to reference the hash in answers and comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`actions` is an array so you need to either access a specific index or loop through it.

For example if your hash is called `hsh`:

```
hsh.dig('actions', 0, 'value')
```

This is another way of writing `hsh['actions'][0]['value']` but fails gracefully if any of the elements is nil.

or...

```
hsh['actions'].map { |action| action['value'] }
```

returns `['click_me_123']`

Comment: Perfect. Works, thank you.

Comment: "failing gracefully" is precisely the reason you should not use `dig` here. A return value of `nil` means there's a bug in the code or a problem with the data. Wouldn't it better to use `hsh['actions'][0]['value']`, which would raise an exception if the code did not match the data? A return of `nil` (by `dig`) might not cause problems for some time, making debugging more difficult. I think you mean `'This is...'` rather than `'(this is...'`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland No, I don't agree that a return value of nil mean's there's a bug in the code or a problem with the data. The response is still valid if there are no actions.

Comment: Andy wishes to stab out a value from a hash whose structure is known, namely the value at `hsh['actions'][0]['value']`. Here it is `"click_me_123"`. It could be something else, but its not `nil`. Now suppose he wrote  `hsh.dig('action', 0, 'value')`. (Note the spelling error.) `nil` would be returned and that may not raise an exception for some time. By contrast, `hsh['action'][0]['value']` would raise an exception right away, which is what you want. My advice is that you are looking for trouble by using `dig` when you know the object's structure. And what is to be gained?

Comment: Raising an exception isn't helpful if I only care whether the value is nil or not. If you had a typo it would never return 'click_me_123' so you'd immediately know something is wrong. The object's structure also isn't fixed even if it's known. If `actions` is empty then your suggestion will need several extra lines to do the same thing as you'd have to check for nil at each level. The same exception would be raised if actions was missing or empty - all it tells you is that there's a nil somewhere in your chain. Better to write a `valid_actions?` method in that case.